# With swagger 2.0 (or even 3.0), is it possible to mark an enum value as deprecated?

Tags: enums, swagger, openapi, swagger-2.0

We use a Java type generator to modify our enum type from Swagger 2.0 to a Java enum, and there are cases where we have needed to deserialize enum values that we've removed from our codebase, so for now we need to keep these deprecated enum values.

Can we somehow mark them in Swagger 2.0 as deprecated?  I don't see a way to do so in either Swagger 2.0 or 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is not possible to achieve this with either versions. However as of 3.1 it is possible. Have a look at this article that explains this in depth: https://community.smartbear.com/t5/Swagger-Open-Source-Tools/Swagger-Enum-Deprecated-Values-Is-it-possible/td-p/207289